# Which account to be used for generating Google Maps V2 API Key

Tags: android, google-maps, android-maps-v2

I have used Google Maps V2 in my application and about to submit it to Android play. 
I know how to create maps api key and use it in application, But I am bit confused on which mail account to be used for creating maps api key. Is it Developer console Google Play account used for submitting app OR any other google account.

Is it mandatory to use same application submission account for creating v2 maps key?
Is it ok if we use one account for creating maps api key and other for submitting application?

I was concern on this because, now v2 maps uses google play service jar.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use any Google Account. Go to Google API Console and create a new project for your application and generate key.

Answer (score 0):

You can use any Google Account you want, but I suggest that you use the same account that you use for developing purposes.  If you aren't going to publish the app, it's probably not a big deal.  Just remember that your Maps key will be registered with whatever account you choose, so sometimes it's better to *not* use a personal account.